# Upload Image using Java is not saving properly in the cloud

Tags: java, file, file-upload, web-deployment

My form has an upload button for the user to save file images.

```
ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();

String appPath = context.getRealPath("");
String filePath = appPath+"\\images\\categories";

File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, getMyFileFileName());
FileUtils.copyFile(getMyFile(), fileToCreate);
```

I need to upload the picture and put it on the image/categories folder for future access. It is working well in my localbuild but when I deployed it on the cloud by uploading the .war file, it doesn't work anymore. It cannot find the image.

HTML Error upon accessiing the image is as follow

```
type Status report

message /Teapop/images/categories/team.png

description The requested resource (/Teapop/images/categories/team.png) is not available.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're assuming that the cloud has a persistent file system, that your app will always run on the same host, and that it's a good idea to write in the directory where your webapp is deployed (and that will be deleted at the next deploy). All of these are incorrect assumptions. Save your data in your data store, whatever it is. See slide 43 and following in http://fr.slideshare.net/ndeloof/cloud-patterns-softshake-2013

Comment: assuming it is running on the same host, why is my code not working?

Comment: Well, for a start, I doubt your cloud is running Windows. Only Windows uses backslashes in paths.

Comment: @JB Nizet  thank you. This is my first time to explore aws and i've learned a lot from you. tnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try to use File.separator instead

```
String filePath = appPath+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"categories";
```

and please give me some feedback

Hope that helps .